# How to pass parameters to a dynamic link from flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to navigate a user to a particular page on clicking a shared link based on the id passed in that link. I use dynamic link of Firebase for that. after configuring a dynamic link in the Firebase console manually. I use this code to create a link when sharing an app:

```
Future<Uri> createDynamicLink(String id) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://asbdf.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('https://aspdf.page.link/createpost?id=$id'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.sample.aspdf',
        minimumVersion: 1,
      ),
    );
 
    print(parameters.link);
    final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await dynamicLinks.buildShortLink(parameters);
    final Uri shortUrl = shortLink.shortUrl;
    return shortUrl;
}
```

The sharing link works fine. After sharing the link on social media (whatsapp), when I click on that link, the app opens and causes an error. This is the code to retrieve deeplink:

```
final Uri deepLink = data.link;
print("deeplink found");
print(deepLink);

String? id = deepLink.queryParameters['id'];
print(id.toString());
  Get.offAll(()=>AuthStatus(uid: id!));
```

This is because the app is opening the static deeplink which I configured in the console manually, not the link which was created programatically from the above code. So no parameters are taken by the link and the value of the id variable becomes null and causes an error. How can I fix this problem?